# Gnome Shell or Mutter makes X unusable when I kill/restart/etc. tor

Tags: networkmanager, gnome-shell, socks, tor, mutter

I've configured the system to use Tor by setting the SOCK proxy to port 9050 in Settings -> Network -> Network Proxy.  At times, Tor takes ages to reconnect after the wifi driver crashes or whatever.

Appears `sudo killall -HUP tor` does not put tor right again, so I'd naturally try `sudo systemctl restart tor` instead.

This actually works, if I first switch to a text virtual console.  Tor happily reconnects, usually quickly.  I'm back at a lock screen when I switch back to X, or maybe even logged out, but the system stays up.

If however I do `sudo systemctl restart tor` from a Terminal in X then the system hangs.  I can still move the mouse, at least temporarily, but I cannot interact with anything.  I cannot even switch to a text virtual console from the keyboard.  I donno if `sshd` stays up yet.

I'd imagine `mutter`, or another critical Gnome Shell component, has connections open through Tor, maybe even a connection to `dbus` or X.  And maybe it's a security vulnerability in the guilty process.

How should I go about diagnosing what Gnome Shell processes are talking to Tor, or the internet, that should not be?  Are there AppArmor profiles or similar for Gnome Shell to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use another computer on the local network to ssh into the system prior to restarting `tor` in gnome and get a `top` running, then execute the repro steps. This should give at least a starting point:

- if that ssh session hangs as well it means the entire system is in
  some sort of trouble (my 1st suspect is heavy swapping)
- even if it hangs the running top would snapshot what was going on
  in its last update, might capture something interesting for the
  investigation
- if the session doesn't hang you have a mean to further investigate

Comment: Ain't too likely the who system hangs unless maybe X itself crashes, but the mouse still works and it works from a text virtual console.  I've try using `lsof` to find inappropriate open sockets owned by gnome-shell, etc. but I wonder if a simpler tool exists for this purpose